# Add default value for unknown

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a list of users and a list of vaccines, I'd like to keep track of which vaccines a user has so I have a vaccine_users table as well. I want to display a list of checkboxes in a view, name of vaccine and wether a user has been vaccinated with that particular vaccine.

I'm currently using a ListActivity, which I've understand recycles views so I need to have the data in the cursor, which gives me a bit of trouble since I'd like to only keep track of who has which vaccination, not all the vaccines a user does not have.

So I'd like something like this:

```
userId     vaccineId     hasVaccine
1          2             0
1          2             1
```

I've got tables user, vaccine, vaccine_user and I can query for which vaccine a user has, but  it's the hasVaccine=0 row that gives me trouble since I don't store which vaccine a user doesn't have.

EDIT:
I think left outer join is on the right track, I tried this:

```
SELECT v.name, u._id as userId, vu._id as vaccineId FROM user u LEFT OUTER JOIN vacc_user vu ON u._id = vu.userId LEFT OUTER JOIN vaccine v ON v._id = vu.vaccineId WHERE u._id = 4;
```

And I think it should result in this

```
name        userId     vaccineId
Ebola       4          2
Hepatit A   4          null
```

if the user is vaccinated against Ebola but not Hep A but I just get the Ebola row.

EDIT 2:
Here's the relevant tables in their current form, created for sqllite3 but will hopefully work for MySql as well.

```
CREATE TABLE user (_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text not null default 'unnamed');
CREATE TABLE vacc_user(_id integer primary key autoincrement, userId integer not null default 0, vaccineId integer not null default 0);
CREATE TABLE vaccine (_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text default 'unnamed vacc', text text default 'no desc');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second issue (after the edit) is becasue as far as SQL is concerned, anything with a null in the comparison is false.

You have two options:

1) Change your query to use an OR to cover the null contingency (v._id IS NULL)  so you would have:

```
SELECT v.name, u._id as userId, vu._id as vaccineId FROM user u LEFT OUTER JOIN vacc_user vu ON u._id = vu.userId LEFT OUTER JOIN vaccine v ON ((v._id = vu.vaccineId) OR (v._id IS NULL)) WHERE u._id = 4;
```

2) Add entries to your table for those vaccinations not received and use default entries (maybe "nv" for "not vaccinated") either in the SQL table definition itself or though program code, and then you should achieve the results you desire with that query.

Answer (score 1):

easy: you INSERT a record into vaccine_user only if the user took the vaccine (and you can omit the last column)

Comment: but I want to list all the vaccines regardless of whether a user has been vaccinated with it or not.

Comment: then loop the users and inside the loop - loop the vaccines: if there is a record - the user took it, else, he/she did not take it.

Comment: the problem is that all the data need to be in the result from the query

Comment: @dutt all the data is there - a user either did didn't get a vaccine, no ?

Comment: ah, no. i only store the vaccine a user has. i don't store the ones the user doesn't have.

Comment: @dutt right! so when a user does not have a record for a certain vaccine - it means he didn't take it!

Comment: The problem is that i need to have a record created in the query to show that he didn't take it. Like the left outer join in the other answer.

Comment: @dutt if you follow my suggestion you won't need it!

Comment: I don't have a choice in the matter due to the fact that I'm developing for android. The GUI-elements are recycled and set from the query result.

Comment: @dutt but the content of the query is up to you, no ? please share with us the code that preforms the INSERT and the SELECT and I'll show you how to modify it. In general, the idea is to keep only one line per <user,vaccination> and to update it according to the users' input.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement properly, it seems like a simple case of using a `left outer join` query.
Left outer join will join rows that do not have a match with an empty row (all values will be null). So you can have a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM user u LEFT OUTER JOIN vaccine_user vu ON u.id = vu.user_id LEFT OUTER JOIN vaccine v ON v.id = vu.vaccine_id WHERE v.id=null;
```

You can probably make an other join with the vaccine table to get all the vaccines a user has not had if vaccine.

Note: the query is not exact since I I'll need to have the tables and stuff to write something that is accurate but I think you get the point.

Comment: I think you're on the right track, added a bit more info about my attempt.

Comment: If you need more help, we need the DDL's for the tables so we can repro them and test the queries... preferrably for MySQL. If you can integrate hibernate into the app, the query would be a lot simply in HQL.

Comment: WHERE v.id = null will not work.  Any SQL with a comparison to null will return unknown.

Comment: More help would be greatly appreciated, schemas added.